# hyperlink field in table doesnt work

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table that has a  hyperlink field, with the records being a website link, to look up the UPS Worldship shipment tracking#.   My problem is that even though the text has blue colored font, the link doesn’t launch and open the web browser when I click on the field.

originally the hyperlink did work, when I created the table and changed the field properties from “text” to “hyperlink”, but once I ran a delete query and an append query (in order to refresh the data), the link no longer functioned, even though the field has hyperlink properties.

Here is an example of my hyperlink record that I want the browser to launch: http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?sort_by=status&tracknums_displayed=1&TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&loc=en_us&InquiryNumber1=1Z1467826772975386&track.x=0&track.y=0

Please advise what I need to do in order to make the hyperlink work, so the user doesn’t have to manually copy and paste the link into a web browser.

Thank you very much in advance
Nathaniel, Access 2003

---

I don't understand what you mean.  I need to create an Access app that would be used throughout the day in order to track UPS packages.  Ideally the table would provide a link, so that the user doesnt have to manually copy and paste the tracking number into the UPS website.  Please advise if this is feasible without VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not like hyperlink fields, they are difficult to edit and somewhat confusing for the user. I prefer to use a click event with FollowHyperlink. However, if you must use hyperlink fields, they have to have this format to work:

```
 Descriptive text#link#
```

So

```
 Stackoverflow#http://stackoverflow.com#
 http://stackoverflow.com#http://stackoverflow.com#
 Email#mailto:mail@example.com#
```

I imagine you have lost the link - that is, the bit between the hash signs.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question.  I neglected to mention that I dont know VBA.  Is there a wayto make my link usuable with out VBA?

Comment: @Nathaniel You can update your hyperlink field with a query or two. It might be easiest to put them in a text, if they are short, or memo field first, so you can see what they look like. You can do this with cut and paste. Once they are in the text field, they will be a lot easier to edit or update with queries.

Comment: The problem was that I was missing hash signs.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try going back to the table with the record and change the data type to short text. Close and reopen the table and switch the data type back to hyperlink. If the text is a valid webpage link it should work without any extra coding. 
Good luck!